# how to search in django models if some fields are not required

Tags: django, models

so in my models i've got `blank=True` fields. I also have search in this model, but if some fields are `blank=True` user can not fill this fields. And what should I do if some fields are empty?

For example I have model with name and surname(blank=True). If surname not fill in search form i should make one filter, but if surname is fill I should make FILTER with surname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have a really ridicules situation. In my model I make some fields `blank=True` and forgot to do makemigrations! So don't forget to make migrations

Answer (score 1):

Following is usually handy when you have to build filters from long list of form data.

```
import operator
from django.db.models import Q
filter_list = [Q(name=name)]
if surname:
    filter_list.append(Q(surname=surname))

YourModel.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, filter_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a QS in parts:

```
def you_view(request, name, surname):
    # ... Get you filter parameters, just an example.
    qs = MyModel.objects.filter(name=name)
    if surname:
        qs = qs.filter(surname=surname)
    # work with qs
```

This will filter by `surname` only if there is a `surname` variable in  your view.